# Pandas,compact dataframe - Coalesce multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've this dataframe

```
df_stack = ([['age', 0.0417084448844436],
 ['age', 0.0417084448844436],
 ['sex', 0.0506801187398187],
 ['sex', 0.0506801187398187],
 ['bp', 0.1506801187],
 ['bp', 0.1506801187]])
```

I need to get this result

```
     age         bp       sex
0   0.041708    0.15068   0.05068   
1   0.041708    0.15068   0.05068
```

When I pivot the table with:

pd.DataFrame(df_stack).pivot( columns=[0], values=[1])

I get this result

```
    1
    age         bp      sex
0   0.041708    NaN     NaN
1   0.041708    NaN     NaN
2   NaN         NaN     0.05068
3   NaN         NaN     0.05068
4   NaN        0.15068    NaN
5   NaN        0.15068    NaN
```

I was thinking about iterating over all columns values and concatenate after each column

```
import math
age = []
for c, v in test.iterrows():
    print (v['age'])
    if math.isnan(v['age']) == False:
        age.append(v['age'])
age
[0.0417084448844436, 0.0417084448844436]
```

But I need to go through this procedure for each column, which is not very adequate when we've 40 features.
The issue, we can't assign a column as variable, otherwise I could append for each column name.

If someone has a better idea that would help me a lot.

Comment: check question10

Comment: Yes I did, and it's completely out of scope. You should also read the entire question before close.

Comment: OK, so solution from `answer10` not working? It should be.

Comment: it should. but isn't.  Maybe I've not formulated my question properly, and I shouldn't use "Pivoting" because it's misleading with "Pivot" subjects when there's no relationship. So could you please unlock my question? Gratefully thanks

Comment: Sure, I can unlock it, only show how solution from Q/A10 not working for you.

Comment: Solution from Q/A10 do not "coalesce" values.  If you check my request, the results do not contains "nan" compared with results in provided solution.

Comment: yop, if use this solution no nan problem, solution working well, because need pivot 2 columns df.